# Is there a way to give coupon codes for people to download your app for free?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, coupon

I am repeating this question, but it has been a year since it has been asked. Is it currently possible to provide coupon codes to people to download your app for free?

Looking on another forum I found this picture:
[image]

I was wondering if it could easily be used, or used the way I'm thinking it would be (google generates a gift code, and you distribute it)

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way for developers to generate codes to use on their applications. You can, however, use [in-app licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html), but that requires extra work.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5OOJDIrYls) from Google I/O 2013, it's still not possible.